# LG DoublePlay: Boot looping after replacing framework-res.apk

Tags: unbricking, boot-loop, lg-doubleplay

I modified and replaced the original `framework-res.apk` on my *LG DoublePlay (C729)* and now it keeps bootlooping on T-Mobile logo. Even the recovery mode didn't help - the recovery mode displays only a unpacking icon and then it reboots the phone. I have the original `framework-res.apk` but I'm not able to get it into my phone. USB connection with PC is stable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If the USB connection is stable, try using `adb push` to push the apk in the right place.

Comment: The command "adb devices" returns an empty list. Do I need a specific driver for it?

Comment: Normally the adb drivers are included with your phone, one thing I did overlook is that USB debugging needs to be enabled ahead of time.

Comment: Well, it was enabled, but the recovery mode restored the settings to default.

Comment: @A--C That is incorrect. ADB drivers are separate .exe files - IE drivers that are needed by Windows to use the ADB interface.

Comment: Too late to edit the comment, I meant included with the phone software, if you install the phone drivers, they almost always include the adb drivers.

Comment: In that case, how can I check if the drivers are present?

Comment: You could check for a supported driver here on http://www.lgforum.com/how_do_is/installing-usb-drivers-for-the-optimus-vortex-and-ally-android-phones

Comment: I have exactly those drivers installed.

Comment: I somehow managed to get into recovery - ADB work there, but when I type push, ls, su, mount etc. it returns permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything can be done at this point, you should've been more careful when you messed with Android System itself. If it was SystemUI your phone would reboot into system, but unfortunately that ain't the case. The only reasonable thing to do would be flashing a new ROM.

ADB won't work until your phone reboots to system. I don't think fastboot will help you either, so that leaves only one option, flash it.

Next time you try to change either "framework-res.apk" or "SystemUI.apk" try this script.
It will get the job done without any mess.
Remember to run the script as root and put the apk files in external sdcard(extsd).

```
#!/system/bin/sh

mount -o rw,remount /system


if [ -f "/extsd/framework-res.apk" ]
then
    cat /extsd/framework-res.apk > /system/framework/framework-res.apk 
    chown 0.0 /system/framework/framework-res.apk
    chmod 0644 /system/framework/framework-res.apk
else
    echo "Error: File(s) not found."
fi

if [ -f "/extsd/SystemUI.apk" ]
then
    cat /extsd/SystemUI.apk > /system/priv-app/SystemUI.apk 
    chown 0.0 /system/priv-app/SystemUI.apk
    chmod 0644 /system/priv-app/SystemUI.apk
else
    echo "Error: File(s) not found."
fi

reboot
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Have a backup of your system in case of problems.
2. Root your tablet if not already rooted.
3. Install a file manager with system r/w capability.
4. Copy the framework-res.apk from wherever you have it stored to \system. Do not copy the file to \system\framework at this point or you will cause the system to bootloop.
5. Change the file permissions to rw-r--r--.
6. Move framework-res.apk from \system to \system\framework, letting it overwrite the original. You will have been successful if the phone does not instantly reboot upon copying.
7. Completely power down your phone, then power it back up.

Comment: The user is using a phone not a tablet, they are unable to install any apps and/or root the phone because it is bootlooping and they also said that they can't push or anything because of root issues.